# Extracting texture features from images by GLCM

Tags: python, image-processing, feature-extraction, scikit-image, glcm

I'm using GLCM to get texture features from images to use them in classification algorithms like knn and decision tree. When I run the `greycoprops` function it returns an array of 4 elements for each feature as follows. Should I get the average of each feature to be used in my classification or how should I deal with them?

```
('Contrast = ', array([[0.88693423, 1.28768135, 1.11643255, 1.7071733 ]]))
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycoprops), this is what `greycoprops` returns:

> `results` : 2-D ndarray
>
> > 2-dimensional array. `results[d, a]` is the property `‘prop’` for the `d`’th distance and the `a`’th angle.

You are getting a 1×4 array of contrast values because you passed 4 angles to `graycomatrix`. In order for the GLCM descriptor to be rotation-invariant it is a common practice to average the feature values computed for different angles and the same distance. Have a look at [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patrec.2014.04.006) for a more in depth explanation on how to achieve GLCM features that are robust against rotation.

#### Demo

```
In [37]: from numpy import pi

In [38]: from skimage import data

In [39]: from skimage.feature.texture import greycomatrix, greycoprops

In [40]: img = data.camera()

In [41]: greycoprops(greycomatrix(img, distances=[1], angles=[0]), 'contrast')
Out[41]: array([[34000139]], dtype=int64)

In [42]: greycoprops(greycomatrix(img, distances=[1, 2], angles=[0]), 'contrast')
Out[42]: 
array([[ 34000139],
       [109510654]], dtype=int64)

In [43]: greycoprops(greycomatrix(img, distances=[1, 2], angles=[0, pi/4]), 'contrast')
Out[43]: 
array([[ 34000139,  53796929],
       [109510654,  53796929]], dtype=int64)

In [44]: greycoprops(greycomatrix(img, distances=[1], angles=[0, pi/4, pi/2]), 'contrast')
Out[44]: array([[34000139, 53796929, 20059013]], dtype=int64)
```